# Trying to output 10 lines using for loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the following output when entering a number into the program:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhjlR.jpg

But I only get one line instead of all ten.
Can someone walk me through this?
Thank you.
My code below:

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
char ans='y';
int num = 0;
while (ans=='y' || ans=='Y')
{
system("cls");
system("color f0");
cout<<"\t\t\t****************************************"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t*                                      *"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t*                                      *"<<endl;                   
cout<<"\t\t\t*      Square-Cube Program             *"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t****************************************\n"<<endl;
cout<<"Please enter a number to square,cube, and raise to the 4th power: ";
cin>>num;
cout<<"\t"<<"Number"<<"\t"<<"Square"<<"\t"<<"Cube"<<"\t"<<"4th Power"<<endl;
cout<<"\t"<<"------"<<"\t"<<"------"<<"\t"<<"----"<<"\t"<<"---------"<<endl;
for(int num=0; num<100; num++,num+=5){
    cout<<"\t"<<num<<"\t"<<pow(num,2.0)<<"\t"<<pow(num,3.0)<<"\t"<<pow(num,4.0)<<endl;
cout<<"Would you like to continue (Y or N)? ";
cin>>ans;
}
cout<<"\n\t\t\tT H A N K  Y O U"<<endl;
system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you only get one line with results?

Comment: Nearly had a heart attack when I saw you got `while (ans=='y' || ans=='Y')` right.

Comment: This doesn't even compile (you're missing a `}`)

Answer (score 4):

I think you meant to do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    cout<<"\t"<<num<<"\t"<<pow(num,2.0)<<"\t"<<pow(num,3.0)<<"\t"<<pow(num,4.0)<<endl;
    num+=5;
}
```

Comment: The following line has to be used:
`for(int num=0; num<100; num++,num+=5)`

Comment: You mean it's required by your professor? But it really doesn't make any sense. You got `num` from a user input that could be any number, and then you're trying to start out the calculation with it being equal to zero. Not to mention that syntax doesn't make any sense, you can't do `num++` and `num+=5` simultaneously.

Comment: Did you try to use the code I suggested and observe the output? Because I am pretty sure that it will produce the results you have shown in the attached .png.

Comment: I meant 10, not 100. Where is missing bracket?

Comment: So there's not a limitation on how high `num` can go? See updated answer.

Comment: it's suppose to output the square, cube, quad on 10 lines and add 5 to number on each line.

Comment: The code in my answer will do that. It loops ten times starting with the `num` entered by the user. After it does the calculations and outputs the results, it will add 5 to `num` and do it again (for ten times).

Comment: @tanderson No problem and good luck. I'll check again later, if something doesn't make sense to you or if you have some other problem. The missing `}` that was mentioned earlier corresponds to the `main`, `while`, and `for`, each should have an opening and a closing bracket. In the code you posted above the (incorrect) `for` loop is missing it's closing `}`.